# Symfony 4 Sorting Filtered Array Collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having trouble sorting a collection resulting from a one-to-many relationship that has been filtered. I have a quiz that has questions:

```
class Quiz
{
/**
 * One quiz has many questions. This is the inverse side.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="assessment")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"num" = "ASC"})
 */
 private $questions;

 public function __construct() {
    $this->questions = new ArrayCollection();
 }
```

This works as expected. However, when I modify the getter to exclude inactive (soft-deleted) questions, the sort order is lost.

```
public function getQuestions()
{
    // filter to never return soft deleted questions
    $criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true));
    return $this->questions->matching($criteria);
}
```

In fact, with this getter in place, if I modify the order by clause to a nonexistent column, I do not get an unrecognized field exception as I would expect:

```
@ORM\OrderBy({"nonexistantcolumn" = "ASC"})
```

This leads me to believe that somehow the criteria filtering is overriding the annotation. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides filtering, `Criteria` can also [sort](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.html#method_orderBy) a collection:

```
public function getQuestions()
{
    // filter to never return soft deleted questions
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true))
        ->orderBy(["num" => Criteria::ASC]);
    return $this->questions->matching($criteria);
}
```

However, consider adding another unfiltered getter since this will prevent you from actually deleting inactive elements, or moving this logic to a repository method.